# Login script not running

Tags: windows-7, samba, netlogon

I have a server running Debian Wheezy, and Samba 3 running the Domain Controller. The clients are Windows 7, and mostly work. One issue I'm having on one computer is that it will log in, and present the desktop, but without running the log on script. Later in the same calendar day, it will run the script if the user logs out and logs back in. Checking the Event Log, I see this error description:

```
This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain JMC due to the following: 
The RPC server is unavailable. 
This may lead to authentication problems. Make sure that this computer is connected to the network. If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator.
```

The same image works on other systems, so I don't feel that the image is the culprit. Where can I look for getting help with this issue, or to find out what is causing it?

I've checked:

- The user can access the login script, and run it manually without errors
- The user can read all the files in the \server\netlogon folder
- The time is within seconds of the server, same time zone (PST)
- Affects any user who logs in first after starting up the machine
- No Group Policies are being pushed by the server, only local policies

Answer (score 0):

Name resolution problems maybe? From the client, can you try running (replacing your domain name with the correct one):

```
nltest /dsgetdc:mydomainname.com
```

Comment: It pulls the correct DC and Address